# Create local variable in Angular template

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6.

I would like to assign a local variable in for loop to avoid multiple call of the method.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <!-- Declare someItem variable here -->
    <!-- let someItem = getSomeItemFromDifferentDataStructureUsingSomeLogic(item) -->
    {{ someItem.name }}
    {{ someItem.anotherValue }}
</li>
```

I don't also want to make a separate component to display `someItem` cause it is too trivial to create separate one.

What would be your's approach?

Many thanks for a help.

Comment: Your best approach would be to handle this in your component before displaying it in the html template.

Comment: No way to do it like you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `map` items to `someItem`s in compontent code and interate over it

In compontent:

`someItems=items.map(this.getSomeItemFromDifferentDataStructureUsingSomeLogic.bind(this))`;

and in template

```
<li *ngFor="let someItem of someItems">
    {{ someItem.name }}
    {{ someItem.anotherValue }}
</li>
```

In case if you need in this `*for` loop original item, just create an array of item-someItem pairs and iterate over that, using what is needed respectively.

Comment: As I thought. I need to prepare whole data to display in component code.